# encoding changes after conversion char* to string

Tags: c++

I am reading a char[] from socket with this code:

```
char* Beam::receive_msg()
{   
    char szResponse[50] = "";
    int retVal = recv(clientSocket, szResponse, 50, 0);
    ...        

    printf("Got the response from server\n%s\n",szResponse);
    return szResponse;
}
char *temp = receive_msg();
string msg = string(temp);
```

I get the message in `temp` that I want - "(0.1,0.1)", but in `string msg` I got another string with cyrillic symbols.

Can you help me how to solve it?

Comment: You are returning a pointer to something that no longer exists. The `szResponse` array exists only while `receive_msg` is running, so returning a pointer to it makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `szResponse` is a local variable on the stack. You are returning a pointer to a local variable, when you dereference that pointer you get undefined behavior as that memory is no longer valid once the function exits.

One solution would be to change your member function to return an `std::string` instead.

Also, make sure you are compiling with high warning levels, as I'm pretty sure most compilers will give a warning for this.

Answer (score 1):

Although Jesse's answer is the best, the simplest solution is to change the buffer to `static` storage duration so it persists after the function call.

```
static char szResponse[50];
```

Although best practice is to always initialize variables, you might not write an initializer with `szResponse`. It will be zeroed anyway, and `""` misleadingly causes it to appear to store a string, which it doesn't. Note that `recv` is not a string-based function, and it doesn't add a NUL terminator, so you should do so manually yourself. Otherwise the `printf` may cause a buffer overflow. (This isn't necessary if you receive directly into the underlying buffer of `std::string`.)

Also, `static` implements a global variable, this solution would render `receive_msg` not re-entrant. It couldn't be called simultaneously from two threads.

Avoiding C strings and buffers entirely in favor of `std::string` is definitely the best solution.

Comment: ("It will be zeroed anyway" only applies if it's declared `static`. Now I see that your local variable initialization does add a null terminator by virtue of `recv` not modifying bytes besides the message, but buffer overflow could still occur if 50 bytes are received. Best to explicitly write the NUL after `recv`.)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
char* Beam::receive_msg()
{   
    char szResponse = new char[50];
    int retVal = recv(clientSocket, szResponse, 50, 0);
    ...        

    printf("Got the response from server\n%s\n",szResponse);
    return szResponse;
}
char *temp = receive_msg();
string msg = string(temp);
delete(temp);
```

Or:

```
void Beam::receive_msg(char *szResponse)
{   
    int retVal = recv(clientSocket, szResponse, 50, 0);
    ...        

    printf("Got the response from server\n%s\n",szResponse);
}
char temp[50];
receive_msg(temp);
string msg = string(temp);
```

Comment: -1, what's the point of having a separately owned buffer besides the one managed by `string`?